Primeng 11.2.3 p-autocomplete list display the list of previous search
I am using PrimeNG auto-complete as follows:
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="suggestion" 
   (completeMethod)="searchSuggestions($event)" 
   [suggestions]="searchSuggestionsResult" field="field"></p-autoComplete>

The problem is that when I type a letter in the input box, the search results return a list that match the previous search.
For example if I typed "E" - nothing is retrieved even though minLength="0", if I type "EB" a list that match to the search for "E" is displayed. I checked the list returned from "searchSuggestions" function, and the list is correct.
I tried to add attribute of: [immutable]=false, But I got an error:

Can't bind to 'immutable' since it isn't a known property of 'p-autocomplete'

version of PrimeNG: 11.2.3, version of Angular: 11.2.1

please sahre the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated
